# UIView appears with wrong center position

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

In the following function I define all the necessary characteristics of a UIView:

```
func OpenController() {
    var gameOverView: UIView = UIView()

    gameOverView.center = super.view.center
    gameOverView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
    gameOverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    self.view.addSubview(gameOverView)
}
```

Even though I define the center of the UIView "gameOverView" as that of the the viewcontroller it resides in, it appears with a corner in the center of the viewcontroller and not centered in the viewcontroller. I have tried various other ways of defining the position (NSLayoutConstraints, frame.x, frame.y etc.) but all have this result.

If anyone can tell me why this happens and how to center the UIView within its parent view controller I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: have you tried first setting the gameOverView's size an then specify its size?

Comment: Setting its size before the position makes it work, thanks!

Comment: I am glad to have helped you! I also have made an answer with a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue here is that your center is being set before the frame. Since you are creating the view without the frame argument your frame is {0, 0}.

So you are currently centering the subview then resizing it, so this is happening:

[image: Centering a {0, 0} subview]
[image: Resizing after centering the {0, 0} subview]

What you need to do is resize the subview then center it, like this:

[image: Resizing a subview]
[image: Centering a subview]

So you can just swap your centering and framing logic:

```
gameOverView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
gameOverView.center = super.view.center
```

Otherwise even easier just pass the frame when creating the view (you could even pass in the proper x, y coordinates to center it here too):

```
var gameOverView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300))
```

Comment: Hey, you really saved so much headache :) Thanks for the answer, I have been making the same mistake and banging my head into a wall over and over

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the center of the view after setting its size. This is because before setting the size or frame of a view its frame rect is (x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0). If you then immediately set its center, then a view of size zero will get centered so its new frame rect could be (x:20,y:20,width:0,height:0) (if the parent view is 40x40). If you now change the view's size, the origin point of the view will not actually move so the new frame could be (x:20,y:20,with:5,height:5) which means the view is no longer centered.

So to center a view you have to first set its size and the its center.